# Object object is rendered instead of html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I'm trying to replace certain substrings in plain text with html and render them back to the user.

I have the following set up now, but it always renders `[Object object]` instead of the html TextField.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const CTextField = (
  <TextField id="outlined-basic" variant="outlined" />
);

function getAll(sourceStr) {
  return sourceStr.replace(/{_}/gi, CTextField);
}

export default function Parse(props) {
  const data = getAll(props.data);
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: data }}></div>
        {data}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I saw a lot of questions like this, but I tried them and didn't work. I tried setting it as an array `[]` but still got it. I'm even leaving the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in this to show that it doesn't work still.

Comment: `String.prototype.replace` always produces a string, but you need an array of strings and `TextField`s (and to not use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`). Look into `split` or `match`.

Comment: @Ry- That was it! Want to post it as an answer so I can mark it? I used
  `const temp = sourceStr.split("{_}")`
  `return [...temp].map((e, i) => i < temp.length - 1 ? [e, CTextField] : [e]).reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b))` to be specific, do you think there's a more efficient way?

Comment: I missed this comment or never got notified about it, sorry! In case it’s still useful to you today, there is a more efficient way: `return temp.flatMap((e, i) => i > 0 ? [CTextField, e] : [e])`. `reduce`/`concat` is quadratic, so you should always prefer `flatMap` when supported by your target environment (polyfills and standalone function equivalents available if not).